# Is it right that android sdk for 64-bit has it's executable file shows some info about 32-bit?

Tags: android, linux, bash

I am working on a 64-bit linux system(it's ubuntu), and downloaded a ADT Bundle for 64bit linux, but when I use some tools under the sdk folder, the bash report some error like

```
bash: ./emulator: No such file or directory
```

What can cause error like this, I am aware the file is just there.some infomation I can get are showed below:

```
$ uname -a
Linux zhch-DX4840 3.8.0-34-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 18:00:10 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ pwd
/home/zhch/software/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools
# the path indicates that I downloaded a 64bit version, I downloaded it from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

$ ls ./emulator
./emulator
$ ./emulator
bash: ./emulator: No such file or directory
$ file emulator
emulator: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, not stripped
```

Or there is something wrong about the ADT Bundle?

PS: I downloaded the 64bit version, so I think there tools should can be used without configure, isn't it?

Comment: After downloading, did you upgrade the bundle?

Comment: You must upgrade the SDK and then try executing your commands.

Comment: ok , I'll have a try, thanks

Comment: nothing happened after the upgrade, and I think the problem has no relation about upgrade, it just installed some new version of tools

Comment: Yes with that you get The ADB which is necessary to run commands from terminal.

Comment: I am sure some file or Directory is missing from your Platform-tools directory and hence the error.

Comment: Also make sure that your SDK folder on linux is named as Android-SDK-Linux. Go through this: https://nookdeveloper.zendesk.com/entries/22167968-Ubuntu-Linux-Getting-ADB-working\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to install some 32 bit libraries as well. Try `ldd emulator`, this should tell you which libraries can be resolved and which can't. The 'no such file or directory' when executing a file that's obviously there results from a library that can't be resolved.

Comment: ldd emulator reported: not a dynamic executable

Comment: it sames really that the system lacks some 32bit libs, I get some tips form [here](http://altairhw.blog.163.com/blog/static/7942760520101824839585/), and use `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` resolved the probolem.